# Correct functions not called run-time

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to generalize a data processing logic with first-class functions. Below you'll find the minimal simplified example to illustrate the run-time failure.

Why the Ballerina project below crashes run-time with the following output and error:

```
$ ballerina run so001
Compiling source
        xxx/so001:0.1.0

Creating balos
        target/balo/so001-2019r3-any-0.1.0.balo

Generating executables
        target/bin/so001.jar

Running executables

bar:data
fooConversion: {"bar":"bar"}
error: {ballerina}TypeCastError message=incompatible types: 'error' cannot be cast to 'string'
        at xxx.so001:$lambda$1(main.bal:18)
           xxx.so001:$lambda$0(main.bal:14)
           xxx.so001:main(main.bal:25)
```

As you can see above it looks like `fooConversion()` is called with `bar` data and not with `foo` data as expected.

The expected output is:

```
$ ballerina run so001
Compiling source
        xxx/so001:0.1.0

Creating balos
        target/balo/so001-2019r3-any-0.1.0.balo

Generating executables
        target/bin/so001.jar

Running executables

foo:data
fooConversion: {"foo":"foo"}
bar:data
barConversion: {"bar":"bar"}
[{"unified":"foo"}, {"unified":"bar"}]
```

**The code**

```
$ cat src/foo/main.bal 
import ballerina/io;

public function data() returns map<json> {
    io:println("foo:data");
    return {foo: "foo"};
}
```

```
$ cat src/bar/main.bal 
import ballerina/io;

public function data() returns map<json> {
    io:println("bar:data");
    return {bar: "bar"};
}
```

```
$ cat src/so001/main.bal 
import ballerina/io;

import xxx/foo;
import xxx/bar;

public function main() {
    json[] unified = [];

    var unifier = function (
        function () returns map<json> get,
        function (map<json>) returns map<json> convert
    ) {
        var j = get();
        unified.push(convert(j));
    };
    var fooConversion = function (map<json> j) returns map<json> {
        io:println("fooConversion: ", j.toJsonString());
        return {unified: <string>j.foo};
    };
    var barConversion = function (map<json> j) returns map<json> {
        io:println("barConversion: ", j.toJsonString());
        return {unified: <string>j.bar};
    };
    // works as expected if only one of the unifier() functions is called
    unifier(foo:data, fooConversion);
    unifier(bar:data, barConversion);

    io:println(unified.toJsonString());
}
```

If I put the code above into one file it works as expected.

I'm using Ballerina 1.0.5 in Ubuntu 19.04:

```
$ ballerina version
Ballerina 1.0.5
Language specification 2019R3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the code generation logic, I have created an issue [1] to track this, and the fix is in the PR [2]

The issue here is since two methods you are using has the same name("data"), a lambda we create internally messes up, so until the fix is merged, can you use two different names for the "data" method

[1] - https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/20401

[2] - https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/pull/20402

Comment: The code is under my control so I could change the functions names to avoid the name collision. The code works as expected when the function names are different.